# didSelectRowAt not getting called

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, swift3

I have added UITableView on top of UIView. Added tap gesture to UIView using below code:

```
   let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapToClose))
    tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    vwForTouchClose.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

when I select on cell didSelectRowAt not getting called instead gesture method is called.
Below is ur code at didSelectRowAt:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

}
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Can you add proper view hierarchy in your code and in which view you are adding tapGesture

Comment: UIView --> UITableView

Comment: Check that delegate of `UITableView` is set or not also add code of your `didSelectRow`method that you have currently added.

Comment: @Nirav delegate and datasource are set.  
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        
    }

Comment: @Nirav thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to cancel UIGestureRecognizer's touches on the TableView. Use delegate method of Gesture Recognizer:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    if ([touch.view isDescendantOfView:yourTableView]) {

        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: @thewarrior Thank you!! this solved my problem . added tapGesture.delegate = self and UIGestureRecognizerDelegate protocol.

Comment: Welcome mate :)